# Why isn't $\phi$ onto? $\phi:F \to F: \phi(f)(x) \mapsto x \cdot f(x)$ where $F$ is the set of $R \to R$ functions that have derivatives of all orders

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-explanation, group-isomorphism

Why can't it map to the constant function 1? $\frac 1 x$ should work?

This is in Fraleigh Section 13, Exercise 15 for reference.

Here is the question:

> Let $F$ be the set of all functions $f$ mapping $\mathbb{R}$ into
> $\mathbb{R}$ that have derivatives of all orders.
>
> Is the following an isomorphism?
>
> $\langle F, \cdot\rangle$ with $\langle F, \cdot\rangle$ where
> $\phi(f)(x)=x \cdot f(x)$

And the answer:

> It is not an isomorphism because  $\phi$ does not map $F$ onto $F$.
> Note that $\phi f (0) =0 \cdot f(0)=0$ . Thus there is no element of
> $F$ that is mapped by $\phi$ into the constant function 1.

I kind of get what it's saying but also I feel like they arbitrarily decided to write it in that order when instead they could write it like $\phi f (x)=x \cdot f(x)$ And if $f(x)=\frac 1 x$ then $x \cdot f(x) = 1$ so $\phi f(x) = 1$ even at 0, just like we wanted

Comment: $\frac 1x\not \in F$ since it is not defined at $0$.

Comment: Thanks, is not being defined at 0 mean that it's not a mapping, or does it mean that it doesn't have derivatives of all orders?

Comment: Both. It's not a function on $\mathbb R$ because it isn't defined for all reals, and it certainly hasn't got any derivatives at 0.

Comment: Ok thanks for the further clarification lulu. So when someone in math says derivatives of all orders it means derivatives of all orders at every point? $-\frac 1 {x^2}$ "is" a derivative so the wording confuses me and the book never specified. Like if someone says "does $\frac 1 x$ have a derivative?", everyone I know answers "yes" but the answer is actually no?

Comment: It's all a question of domain. If the domain were the positive reals then $\frac 1x$ is perfectly well defined and it has derivatives of all orders. But if the domain is the entirety of the reals, as here, then you have a problem at 0.